# Relating to the work of Václav Hlavatý

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, mp.mathematical-physics, differential-equations

Upon looking for a topic for my phd thesis, I came upon the work of Václav Hlavatý, whose work concerning unified field theory seemed very interesting to me. My question is this; what are some similar questions to those addressed in his papers? I am looking primarily for particularly well defined problems surrounding his work.